# Checking for Out Links with DOORS DXL

Tags: ibm-doors

I am trying to write a simple DXL that checks for out links. More specifically, I want to look through every requirement in a formal module and return the number of items missing an out link:

```
Module m = current  
Object o = null

string objType = ""
Link outLink

int noOutLinkCount = 0

for o in m do {

    objType = o."Object Type"

    for outLink in o -> "*" do {
        if objType == "Req" or objType = "Obj" and outLink == null then noOutLinkCount++
        }
    }

print "No Out Link Count = " noOutLinkCount""
```

For the life of me, I cannot figure out how to do this.  The condition

```
outLink == null
```

does not seem to work.

Note: Checking to make sure the object is of type "Req" (Requirement) or "Obj" (Objective Requirement) is necessary as I do not care about missing links on Headers, images, text objects, etc.

Answer (score 0):

This loop:

```
for outLink in o -> "*" do {
}
```

Will execute for each outlink. It will not execute at all if there are 0 outlinks.

I would structure the code like so:

```
Module m = current  
Object o = null

string objType = ""
Link outLink

int noOutLinkCount = 0

for o in m do {

    objType = o."Object Type" ""

    // Check if the type is right
    if ( ( objType == "Req" ) || ( objType == "Obj" ) ) {
        // Check for any outlinks at all
        bool no_outlink_flag = true
        for outLink in o -> "*" do {
            // If this executes, at least 1 outlink- flag and break
            no_outlink_flag = false
            break
        }
        // If we didn't flag any outlinks, increment
        if ( no_outlink_flag ) {
            noOutLinkCount++
        }
    }
}

print "No Out Link Count = " noOutLinkCount""
```

That should work. Let me know if it does!

Comment: Works perfectly! Very clever solution. Thanks for the help!